# Implementing debounce in react es6

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lodash

I am trying to implement debounce in a search form, frontend framework is react js, using es6.

Few method that are related to this debounce functionality are:

```
handleSearchForm( event ) {
  this.setState( {
    searchAble: event.target.value
  } )
}

search() {
  console.log( this.state.searchAble )
}
```

I am using lodash debounce in the input field `onChange` property, and setting the state in `onKeyUp` property, like this:

```
<input type="text" className="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Search item by SKU, Price, Title etc..."
  onKeyUp={ this.handleSearchForm.bind( this ) }
  onChange={
    _.debounce( () => {
      this.search( this )
    }, 2050 ).bind( this )
  }
/>
```

So the idea is on keyup it will set the value in state called 'searchAble' and onChange this will call the method `search` to perform the search. But its not working properly, it still calling the search method multiple time   completing the typings.

What i am missing here?

Comment: Your approcah is wrong. There is no need of 2 different methods.

Comment: @Ved any examples?

Comment: Sure. I am posting an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://github.com/nkbt/react-debounce-input

please go the repository and follow the instruction. I think it may help you and remember one thing

"Notification of current value will be sent immediately by hitting Enter key. Enabled by-default. Notification value follows the same rule as with debounced notification, so if Length is less, then minLength - empty value '' will be sent back."

example code

```
  <DebounceInput
  type="number"
  onChange={event => this.setState({value: event.target.value})}
  placeholder="Name"
  className="user-name" 
/>
```